# In Xcode12 and SwiftUI, how do you navigate to the next screen after Firebase Google Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12

There seems to be lack of info regarding the newest Xcode because all I have been seeing mentioned ViewController and AppDelegate files, which I do not have...
Instead, I managed to make an AppDelegate class inside my app's main swift file (My project's name is Particeps, and thus the main file is ParticepsApp.swift)

However, I can't figure out how to go from the 'SignInview' to the 'MyCurrentLocationView' once the user is logged in. Below are my codes

ParticepsApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn


@main
struct ParticepsApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            SignInView(info: self.delegate)
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject,UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate,ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var email = ""
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID =
            FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        
        guard let user = user else{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return}
        
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: user.authentication.idToken, accessToken: user.authentication.accessToken)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            self.email = (result?.user.email)!
            print(result?.user.email as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

SignInView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleSignIn

struct SignInView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var info : AppDelegate
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
            }) {
                
                Text("Sign In")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.vertical,10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 45)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            }
            
            Text(info.email)
                .padding(.top,25)
        }
    }
}
```

MyCurrentLocationView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MyCurrentLocationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}

struct Home: View {
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks a lot!